# Jails user in your home

Tags: 14.04, permissions, ssh, home-directory, sshd

I have VPS with many users, but i need jails user in your home.

Example:

```
User1 access
/home/user1/public_html

User2 access
/home/user2/public_html
```

Both can use SSH, but may not have access to /var/www/ or other directory, only /home/$user/

How can I do this?

Ubuntu 14.04
Apache